# what are required jar to run a scala program?

Tags: scala

I want to import below classes into scala program using scala-Eclipse IDE.

import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext;
import org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext;

What are the required jars please suggest.

Comment: Maybe [Spark](http://spark.apache.org), or you can use your search engine to figure out from which project it is ...

Comment: Just pasting the class in the search engine clearly indicate that it comes from Spark. Maybe it means you have to be able to read documentation on this site...

Comment: Then your google-fu is weak. https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=apache+spark+eclipse gives  four or five results  that tell you how to do this on the first page alone.

Comment: I got answer to my question.I got jars from below url http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-sql_2.10/1.0.0 
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-hive_2.10/1.1.0

Answer (score 0):

*Don't* try to pick the jars manually. Especially if you depend on a large project with many dependencies, like Spark. Just use a build system like SBT (or Maven, or Gradle). After you set up your project ([Spark Quick Start](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/quick-start.html) explains how), you can ask it about the jars it needs, if you are still interested for some reason: `sbt "show dependency-classpath"`.